# Installing mailparse.dll for php-mime-mail-parser Problem

Tags: php

I am trying to install the  mailparse.dll so I can use php-mime-mail-parse (from github)
My operating platform is Windows 10 and using PHP 7.4

I download the following file:

```
mailparse-3.1.2.tgz
```

from the following link:

```
http://pecl.php.net/package/mailparse
```

and thought I had extracted it properly using Winzip but there is no mailparse.dll to be found.
What am I doing wrong ??